# How to enable Airplay on raspbmc via SSH?

Tags: raspbmc, audio, ssh

I'd like to enable Airplay on raspbmc via SSH. I don't have a monitor to do it over the GUI. Somehow couldn't find a solution on google.

Comment: Have you solved your problem? If so, please mark the answer that helped you, or if you solved it on your own, create a self-answer and mark it as such. We are trying to get the site Q:A ratio up and marking answers is what does that. If you resolved it and mark then people in the future will be able to profit from what you did *and* it helps move the site closer to graduation. Thanks!

Comment: nah, still don't know. Did it over the GUI, which I wanted to avoid

Comment: Did you try out pete's answer?

Comment: Unfortunately i do not have enough points to add a comment, but i'm too interested in enabling/disabling airplay (or shutting down existing connections) via command-line/ssh. Peters answer requires a reboot of xbmc which is unpreferable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer in [this blogpost](http://joostsmit.blogspot.be/2013/02/openelec-on-raspberry-pi-step-by-step.html).

You have to go ahead and edit the `~/.kodi/userdata/guisettings.xml` file. 
Find the services section and make sure it looks as follows:

```
<services>                                                                 
    <airplay>true</airplay>                                               
    <airplaypassword></airplaypassword>                                   
    <devicename>Mediacenter</devicename>                                 
    <esallinterfaces>true</esallinterfaces>                               
    <escontinuousdelay>25</escontinuousdelay>                             
    <esenabled>true</esenabled>                                           
    <esinitialdelay>750</esinitialdelay>                                   
    <esmaxclients>20</esmaxclients>                                       
    <esport>9777</esport>                                                 
    <esportrange>10</esportrange>                                         
    <upnpannounce>true</upnpannounce>                                     
    <upnprenderer>true</upnprenderer>                                     
    <upnpserver>false</upnpserver>                                         
    <useairplaypassword>false</useairplaypassword>                         
    <webserver>true</webserver>                                           
    <webserverpassword>xbmc</webserverpassword>                           
    <webserverport>80</webserverport>                                     
    <webserverusername>xbmc</webserverusername>                           
    <webskin>webinterface.default</webskin>                               
    <zeroconf>true</zeroconf>                                             
</services>
```

Save the file and restart your xbmc by doing `sudo initctl stop kodi` and `sudo initctl start kodi`.

Now you should see your xbmc showing up as an airplay device.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this will work...
See ~/.xbmc/userdata/guisettings.xml

source:
http://www.wexoo.net/20130330/changing-audio-and-other-settings-in-raspbmc

regards, peter

Comment: Link-only answers are usually discouraged to avoid link-rot.  You should include the most vital information from the link to mitigate against that.

Comment: Try this link.  It has extra preservatives so it won't rot! https://web.archive.org/web/20130619135338/http://www.wexoo.net/20130330/changing-audio-and-other-settings-in-raspbmc

Answer (score 0):

i dont know how to do that on raspbmc, but on  raspbian
you could use rplay as commandline tool. for idevices
you can use sound, video and mirroring and works very well,
but with itunes from imac it will not work until now.

[rplay](http://www.vmlite.com/index.php?option=com_kunena&Itemid=158&func=view&catid=23&id=10991)